# Help with navigating a publication related conversation with my PI

Tags: publications, advisor, communication

I have been working on a research study remotely with my PI for over two years and we finally submitted our paper early last year. We received some promising feedback from the reviewers and had most of the responses ready as of early last year.

Unfortunately, my PI had a few personal issues and we were unable to make some final touches and submit our responses since then. I later heard that my PI's issues were resolved so I tried re-connecting with her via email on multiple occasions. She is still very interested in having our paper published, and even secured industry funding for a follow-up study.

However, its been over a year and we still haven't been able to finalize our response submission. I dont want to pester her with multiple messages but at the same time it would be ideal to have our study published in an important journal, especially when we are so close to the finish line. Any ideas on how I can approach my PI and help navigate this conversation?

Comment: "so I tried re-connecting with her via email on multiple occasions" -- with what outcome?

Comment: Did you just do the new analyses/make the paper changes? Or did you also fully write up the point-by-point rebuttal?

Comment: @ GoodDeeds the response was positive and she said she is working on making final touches to the comments. But this has been the same response over the course of past 6 months with no result.

Comment: @ Dawn It was both but there were a few instances where I wanted my PI's input before finalizing our responses and submitting them to the journal

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion is to write up what you have in a publishable form, including changes you've made based on reviewer feedback. Make a complete document. Send it to her and ask for permission to submit it.

Do the right thing with authorship, however that is perceived in your field, of course. Offer to be "corresponding author" or to defer to her in that if it is appropriate in your field.

But make it easy for her to say yes.